# How to find field names and populate its values?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, web-crawler, casperjs

I have the following HTML form for loggin in to the app:
I am interested only to the "username" and "pwd" field elements of the form.

```
<form name="loginForm" METHOD="post"
    ACTION="/arsys/servlet/LoginServlet"
        enctype="x-www-form-encoded">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="login" nowrap="nowrap" width="20px">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="login" colspan="2" nowrap="nowrap">
        <em class="subhead">Please log in.</em>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="login" nowrap="nowrap" width="20px" >&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="login" nowrap="nowrap" id="LoginLabel-id">
            <b><label style="color:#FFFFFF;" for="username-id">User Name</label></b>
        </td>
        <td>
        <input name="username" maxlength="254" id="username-id" value="" class="loginfield" size="30" type="text">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="login" nowrap="nowrap" width="20px">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="login" id="PasswordLabel-id" nowrap="nowrap">
            <label style="color:#FFFFFF;" for="pwd-id">Password</label>
        </td>
        <td>
        <input name="pwd" maxlength="61" id="pwd-id" class="loginfield" size="30" autocomplete="off" type="password">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="Login" nowrap="nowrap" width="20px">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="Login" name="auth_label" nowrap="nowrap">
            <label style="color:#FFFFFF;" for="auth-id">Authentication</label>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" NAME="auth" id="auth-id" maxlength="2048" class="loginfield" size="30"></td>
    </tr>                           
    <tr>
        <td class="Login" nowrap="nowrap" width="20px">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="loginfield" nowrap="nowrap">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" name="login" value="Log In" onClick="doLogin();"><!--;-->&nbsp;
            <input type="button" name="clear" value="Clear" onClick="clearLogin();"><!--;-->
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="Login" nowrap="nowrap">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="Login" nowrap="nowrap">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="timezone" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="encpwd" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="goto" value="" >
            <input type="hidden" name="server" value="" >
            <input type="hidden" name="ipoverride" value="0">
            <input type="hidden" name="initialState" value="-1">
            <input type="hidden" name="returnBack" value="">
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</form>
```

And here is my 1st attempt with caspejs, since is the only solution that can execute the javascript function that goes together with submitting the form.

```
var utils = require('utils');
var casper = require('casper').create({   
    verbose: true, 
    logLevel: 'debug',
    pageSettings: {
         loadImages:  false,         // The WebPage instance used by Casper will
         loadPlugins: false,         // use these settings
         userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4'
    }
});

// print out all the messages in the headless browser context
casper.on('remote.message', function(msg) {
    this.echo('remote message caught: ' + msg);
});

// print out all the messages in the headless browser context
casper.on("page.error", function(msg, trace) {
    this.echo("Page Error: " + msg, "ERROR");
});

// LOG IN.
var login_url = 'https://usms.upc.biz/arsys/shared/login.jsp';
casper.start(login_url, function() {
   this.test.assertExists('form[name="loginForm"]', 'form is found');
   // utils.dump(this);
   this.fill('form[name="loginForm"]', { 
        'input[name="username-id"]': 'SNIP!', 
        'input[name="pwd"]':  'SNIP!'
    }, true);
});

casper.run();
```

But I am referencing the fields wrongly, and I cannot find how I can list all the field names and how I can access them:

```
PASS form is found
[info] [remote] attempting to fetch form element from selector: 'form[name="loginForm"]'
[error] [remote] findAll(): invalid selector provided "[name="input[name="username-id"]"]":Error: SYNTAX_ERR: DOM Exception 12
[error] [remote] findAll(): invalid selector provided "[name="input[name="pwd"]"]":Error: SYNTAX_ERR: DOM Exception 12
CasperError: Errors encountered while filling form: no field named "input[name="username-id"]" in form; no field named "input[name="pwd"]" in form
```

Could you please advise on how to set the 2 input fields in question,
and then call the `onClick="doLogin();`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the currently latest casperjs 1.1.

In case of [`fill()`](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#fill) you need to specify **element `name`s**:

```
this.fill('form[name="loginForm"]', {
    'username': 'SNIP!',
    'pwd':  'SNIP!'
}, true);
```

You can also use [`fillSelectors()`](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#fillselectors) and locate both the inputs *by id*:

```
this.fillSelectors('form[name="loginForm"]', {
    'input#username-id': 'SNIP!',
    'input#pwd-id':  'SNIP!'
}, true);
```

---

Update and all the credits to Artjom B.

You should wait for the `username` `input` to become present in DOM using [`waitForSelector()`](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitforselector):

> Waits until an element matching the provided selector expression exists in remote DOM to process any next step.

```
casper.waitForSelector("#username-id", function() { 
    this.fill('form[name="loginForm"]', { 
        'username': 'SNIP!', 
        'pwd': 'SNIP!' 
    }, true); 
});
```

Comment: PASS form is found
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.fillSelectors('form[name="loginForm"]', {
    'input#username-id': 'SNIP!',
    'input#pwd-id':  'SNIP!'
 }, true)')

Comment: any ideas why it is null since form is found ?

Comment: @NikosSkalis which casperjs version are you using? (The answer assumes you are on 1.1) Thanks.

Comment: PASS form is found
[info] [remote] attempting to fetch form element from selector: 'form[name="loginForm"]'
CasperError: Errors encountered while filling form: no field named "username" in form; no field named "pwd" in form

Comment: CasperJS version 1.0.2 at /home/nskalis/n1k0-casperjs-76fc831, using PhantomJS version 1.9.0

Comment: @NikosSkalis could you try upgrading to 1.1 and see if the issue persists? Thanks.

Comment: $ casperjs
CasperJS version 1.1.0-beta3 at /home/nskalis/n1k0-casperjs-376d85f, using phantomjs version 1.9.0

Comment: @NikosSkalis do both the options I've presented fail? If yes, what is the error in both cases? Thanks.

Comment: with "fill": [info] [remote] attempting to fetch form element from selector: 'form[name="loginForm"]'
CasperError: Errors encountered while filling form: no field matching names selector "username" in form; no field matching names selector "pwd" in form

Comment: with "fillSelectors": CasperError: Errors encountered while filling form: no field matching css selector "input#username-id" in form; no field matching css selector "input#pwd-id" in form